# Alert Before Page Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've used this code before and have gotten it to work in the past, but now for some reason it wont. I'm trying to alert the user that the submission was successful before redirecting to another page, but the redirect takes place before the alert shows. Everything I've read has indicated that this should work.

```
$.ajax({
    type:   "POST",
    url:    "item.php",
    data:   { rn : rn},
              async: true
      })
        .done(function(){
            alert("The item has been adjusted.");
            window.location.replace("requests.php");
        });
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Likely something else is causing the browser to navigate and the Ajax request isn't even completing.

Comment: The ajax request is completing. The submission works and everything is changed on the database side as it should be. I'll look over my code again and see if I have anything competing with the redirect. Thanks

Comment: At a loss. Stripped down the whole page as much as I could, and still have the same problem. Any reason off the top of your head you can think of that would cause it to skip the alert?

Comment: Had something to do with my settings on this particular browser, I reset them and it's working now.